# Preventing lock wait timeouts with INSERT ... SELECT

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

I have an InnoDB `books` table for my app. A few times a day a very large number of independent `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries run against the `books` table.

Incoming requests to the app also generate a temporary table based on `books` using an `INSERT INTO [tmp table] (SELECT FROM books ...)`.

According to [the MySQL docs on `INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html), this syntax locks on `books` until the temp table has been populated.

The combnination of locks from these selects, inserts, and updates on the `books` table periodically overwhelms MySQL, causing lock wait timeouts.

I've tried a suggestion from [this percona article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/07/12/insert-into-select-performance-with-innodb-tables/) dumping the `SELECT` from `books` into an outfile, doing the `INSERT` as a separate step. This avoids the select locks, but is unreasonably slow loading.

**Am I missing an alternative to the `INSERT ... SELECT` that will not lock the `books` table without sacrificing performance?**

Comment: Please give us some examples of `SELECT FROM books ...`; there may be ways to improve their performance, thereby eliminating the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a MySQL noob and probably understood the problem incorrectly but

```
INSERT INTO [tmp table] (SELECT FROM books ...)
```

should not set any locks to the `books` table but only to the `tmp_table` unless your transaction isolation level is SERIALIZABLE.

UPDATEs could be run on READ COMMITTED isolation level so that InnoDB does not need to hold locks on every row to the end of the transaction (although this works only if the WHERE part consists of indexed columns only).

Comment: Thanks @Croco, this bumped me in the right direction. It seems both `SERIALIZABLE` __and__ `REPEATABLE READ` isolation levels on the `INSERT ... SELECT` transaction lock on the `books` table, preventing writes by other processes. This level if isolation is entirely unnecessary for that query. Setting it to `READ COMMITTED` on my simplified test case solves both issues, 1) writes to `books` can occur in other transactions while the `INSERT ... SELECT` transaction hasn't committed and 2) If a transaction holds a lock on `books` first, the `INSERT ... SELECT` won't be blocked.